# Typescript ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: typescript, module

Trying to implement a module following the [official handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html), I get this error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
>
> at app.js:2

But nowhere in my code do I ever use the name `exports`.

How can I fix this?

---

## Files

#### app.ts

```
let a = 2;
let b:number = 3;

import Person = require ('./mods/module-1');
```

#### module-1.t

```
 export class Person {
  constructor(){
    console.log('Person Class');
  }
}
export default Person;
```

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "scripts/"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you did not type `exports` with an **s** at the end instead of `export`? That would explain the error message as with **s** is wrong.

Comment: i type **export** not *exports*

Comment: any example from repositorie that gona work 10000%

Comment: Where is this being run? On a web page? On a node.js server?  You will need a module loader in the run-time environment that the javascript finally runs in.  From the compiler flags you are using commonjs.  I am not that familiar with commonjs, but you will need to get commonjs set up before Typescript modules will work or you will need to change to another module loader (like require.js) and get that one set up.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

**EDIT:**

This answer might not work depending if you're not targeting `es5` anymore, I'll try to make the answer more complete.

**Original Answer**

If CommonJS isn't installed ([which defines `exports`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15685)), you have to remove this line from your `tsconfig.json`:

```
 "module": "commonjs",
```

As per the comments, this alone may not work with later versions of `tsc`. If that is the case, you can install a module loader like CommonJS, SystemJS or RequireJS and then specify that.

**Note:**

Look at your `main.js` file that `tsc` generated. You will find this at the very top:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

It is the root of the error message, and after removing `"module": "commonjs",`, it will vanish.

Comment: @abhishekkhandait did you check the generated `.js` file after changing the   `tsconfig.json` like I described? Did you re-run `tsc`, does it yield the same error message as before?

Comment: Yeah I recompiled my .ts file and the error still exists after commenting out `"module": "commonJs",` :(

Comment: Ok, please ask a new question (including all relevant output from `tsc`, the beginning of the `.ts` file you're compiling and the beginning of the ouput `.js` file) and link it here, I'll be glad to try and help.

Comment: Doesn't work either for me - using tsc 2.6.1. line is still emitted without "module" : "common.js" in tsconfig file.

Comment: @Matthieu, Were you able to find a solution on 2.6.1? I am facing the same issue and the above answer doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Matthieu Hm, maybe the default behaviour was changed. Can you try `"module": "AMD"` or `"module": "System"`? What other options are you using? Maybe `"None"` could also work if you don't specify `--out-file`. You can find a little more info [here (Ctrl+F "--module")](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Comment: @MaheshVS works with system, as that's what I'm using for loading. Not sure if it would cover every case though.

Comment: @Matthieu I've edited the answer, is that correct now?

Comment: @iFreilicht I guess, but I think ppl will need to setup systemjs to make it work if they don't have it setup already.

Comment: @Matthieu oh, I thought System meant use the system default. I'll make another edit.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50592311/3332734

Comment: If installing CommonJS will make this error go away, then how does one actually install CommonJS? I have spent the better part of an hour Googling, and I cannot find _any_ instructions on how to do so. Can someone _please_ explain?

Comment: @Sturm My answer may be worded confusingly. CommonJS is only a specification. You can find a (not necessarily exhaustive) list of implementations here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS

Comment: Yes, but if I target `es5` in order to display this in every browser then removing `module: "commonjs"` won't resolve the issue and return exactly the same code after compilation. So how to make it work as a browser script (ES5 codebase) without this problem :(

Comment: I'm using electron which uses nodejs (which uses commonJS) and exports is not defined in nodeJs (v11.10.0) so IMHO typescript is generating garbage: it should be using `module.exports` instead of `exports`.

Comment: I have module: amd, not module: commonjs, and I have this line in my transpiled .js file.

Comment: If you have target as ES3 or ES5 in your tsconfig.json then typescript will automatically set your module to CommonJS if it's not defined. Removing module isn't enough, you need to set something else instead - see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: I have this issue, but with "module": "amd". Target is ES5. What else could cause this? Assumption: An imported module causes this. Maybe that module was transpiled for commonjs?

Comment: I had this issue with Node 13. I was giving `package.json` `"type": "module"` a try, and it was not working out too great when trying to use `tsc` and then `node` to run the output.

Comment: I removed it and set the target to es6 and it seems to be working

Answer (score 124):

Add the following line before other references to JavaScript.  This is a nice little hack.

```html
<script>var exports = {};</script>
```

Comment: @ChuckLeButt Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined

Comment: I hate that this works! And it definitely works. Isn't there a way to get TypeScript to transpile into something that Node expects? Is it even Node that's complaining? Or is it the browser? I can't stand not understanding what the problem actually is.

Answer (score 87):

## A solution:

Remove `"type": "module"` from `package.json`.

Comment: but why does this help?

Comment: @DauleDK because we use Webpack to bundle app, this field has usage in node.js engine. in webpack config we ues common module system

Comment: Without this the "import" can't be used.

Comment: Here's a good explanation: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-uncaught-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined#nodejs---referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined

In NodeJS you would instruct TypeScript to generate CommonJS syntax when compiling but with "type": "module" you instruct nodejs to use ES6 modules (which you have compiled away).

Comment: @RobertPazurek very good link! it has explained the issue. I set "module" to "es6" in tsconfig.json and it worked for me.

Comment: it really depends: maybe the OP needs that to interop with ESM packages, consider the original trail that got him to this error... 
it is a good solution, but really it depends on the issue OP's trying to solve.

Answer (score 48):

This is fixed by setting the `module` compiler option to `es6`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {     
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",    
  }
}
```

Comment: This was it for me. Using Laravel Mix with Typescript.

Comment: if you use `nodejs` you need to add `"moduleResolution": "Node"` to `tsconfig.json`

Comment: i am building a nodejs-based command line tool and this worked for me

Comment: Why the different versions for `module` and `target`?

Comment: @mixalbl4 to be precise you need to add it to `"compilerOptions"` in tsconfig

Answer (score 20):

`npm install @babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs`

and add to to .babelrc plugins resolved my question.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share a more detailed code solution. What do I have to add to .babelrc? Is this solution for switching from type commonjs to Module?

Answer (score 16):

I ran into this issue a few weeks ago and used [the exports hack above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46887516/10210463) in the short term but finally figured out another way around this that's working great for me.

So unlike some of the other responses above, I actually wanted the code I'm compiling to be a module. By setting `"target": "es6",` `"module": "esnext"` and then linking to my compiled JS file with `type="module"` instead of `type="text/javascript"`, my compiled code no longer has the `Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });` line and it's still a module

My tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es2016", "esnext", "dom"],
    "outDir": "build",
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "declaration": true,
  },
  "include": ["src/index.ts"],
  "exclude": ["build"]
}
```

My link to my compiled code in HTML `head` tags:

```
<script src="../build/index.js" type="module" defer></script>
```

As a bonus, now I can also import anything that I export in that index.js file in a separate `type="module"` script down below the main HTML `body` code:

```
 <script type="module">
   import { coolEncodingFunction, coolDecodingFunction } from "../build/index.js";
   /* Do stuff with coolEncodingFunction and coolDecodingFunction */
   /* ... */
</script>
```

Comment: `<script Type="Module"` with `"module": "ES2020"` worked for me.

Comment: Error: tsconfig.json(8,15): error TS6046: Argument for '--module' option must be: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es6', 'es2015', 'esnext'.

Answer (score 11):

my solution is a sum up of everything above with little tricks I added, basically I added this to my html code

```html
<script>var exports = {"__esModule": true};</script>
<script src="js/file.js"></script>
```

this even allows you to use `import` instead of `require` if you're using electron or something, and it works fine with typescript 3.5.1, target: es3 -> esnext.

Comment: some progress here, the error just changed to be `app.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Comment: this happens if nodeIntegration is set to false when creating the window, the error happens because you updated your electronJS or you're following an outdated source. nodeIntegration was true by default, now it's false, so you have to enable it manually if you want to access nodeJS in renderer process. See [Electron require() is not defined][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391448/electron-require-is-not-defined

Comment: I'm not using electron, anyway I solved in my case by adding parcel to make bundle stuff and removed other tricky ways

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and solved it adding "**es5**" library to tsconfig.json like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5", //defines what sort of code ts generates, es5 because it's what most browsers currently UNDERSTANDS.
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true, //for angular to be able to use metadata we specify in our components.
        "experimentalDecorators": true, //angular needs decorators like @Component, @Injectable, etc.
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "lib": [
            "es2016",
            "dom",
            "es5"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In **package.json**, add `"type": "module"`

In terminal type in

```
npx tsc --init
```

*It will create a tsconfig.json.*

In **tsconfig.json**,

1. change `"target": "es5"` to `"target": "es6"`
2. comment out `//"module": "commonjs",`
3. uncomment `"moduleResolution": "node",`

You should be good to go.

In **package.json**, create a build script:

```
"build": "tsc -p tsconfig.json"
```

Then, when you want to build, you just compile `npm run build`

then execute and should be good

Answer (score 5):

For people still having this issue, if your compiler target is set to ES6 you need to tell babel to skip module transformation. To do so add this to your `.babelrc` file

```
{
  "presets": [ ["env", {"modules": false} ]]
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I've been trying to work with older code base which dump all into global and scripts are included in browser with the `<script>` tag. I was hoping to use module along with older code and it seems like that is not possible. This at least allow me to use ES6 and let me deal with export later.

Comment: doing this I got the following error: **Using removed Babel 5 option: .modules - Use the corresponding module transform plugin in the `plugins` option. Check out http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#modules**

Answer (score 5):

I had this same error too. In my case it was because we had an old-fashioned import statement in our TypeScript AngularJS project like this:

```
import { IAttributes, IScope } from "angular";
```

which was compiled to JavaScript like this:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

This was needed back in the old days because we then used `IAttributes` in the code and TypeScript wouldn't have known what to do with it otherwise.
But after removing the import statement, and converting `IAttributes` to `ng.IAttributes` those two JavaScript lines disappeared - and so did the error message.

Comment: How would that work for a Typescript type? I have to import it, so Typescript compiles it.

Comment: What do you mean by "Typescript type"? If it's an integeral type known by TypeScript - such as number or string - then you can use that right away. If you define your own types in a module, check this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Comment: I meant the type definitions of an external library like @types/jquery from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery . To make the $ variable usable from within my Typescript code, I put this in my code: import * as $ from "jquery";

Comment: I am targeting es5, do I need another library like requirejs to make this work?

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issue as the original poster of the question:

I better tell you what mistakes I made and how I corrected it, that might help someone.

I had javascript nodejs project and converted it to typescript.

Previously in package.json I had "type":"module" when I was running in JavaScript.

When I converted it to TypeScript project and started converting files in .ts files and started running using following command:

```
npx tsc test.ts && node test.ts
```

I would get the above error.

I got rid of the error by simply removing the "type":"module" from package.json

My tsconfig.json would like below:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "lib": ["es6", "es5", "es7", "dom"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "module": "es6",
        "outDir": "./build",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "build"]
```

I am using node 14 and TypeScript 4.2.4

Answer (score 3):

for me, removing `"esModuleInterop": true` from tsconfig.json did the trick.

Comment: How does removing it work since  `exports` can ONLY be used if `esModuleInterop` is set to true ?

Comment: This worked for me (removed the above error). I'm using ESM with typescript (with jest), so I don't want exports.

Answer (score 3):

First, go to your `index.html` in your public folder find the reference of the script `<script src="myScript.js"></script>` and add `type="module"`

Like so:

```
<script type="module" src="myScript.js"></script>
```

Secondly, in your `tsconfig.json` make sure **target** is set to `es5` and **module** to `es2015`

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5", /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    /* Modules */
    "module": "es2015", /* Specify what module code is generated. */
}
```

**important**: make sure to import with the `.js` extension e.g. `import Piece from './classes/piece.js'`

Answer (score 3):

I have this issue too. then I just change `"module": "commonjs"` to `"module": "ESNext"` everything is working fine.
this my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "ESNext",
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "target": "ESNext",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "outDir": "dist",
    },
    "lib": ["ESNext"],
  }
```

I hope it can solve your problem!

Comment: this work for me! thanks

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `libraryTarget: 'umd'`, like so

```
const webpackConfig = {
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'umd' // Fix: "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined".
  }
};

module.exports = webpackConfig; // Export all custom Webpack configs.
```

Answer (score 2):

Note: This might not be applicable for OP's answer, but I was getting this error, and this how I solved it.

So the problem that I was facing was that I was getting this error when I retrieved a 'js' library from a particular CDN.

The only wrong thing that I was doing was importing from the CDN's `cjs` directory like so:
`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.4.0/dist/cjs/popper.min.js`

Notice the `dist/cjs` part? That's where the problem was.

I went back to the CDN (jsdelivr) in my case and navigated to find  the `umd` folder. And I could find another set of `popper.min.js` which was the correct file to import:
`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.4.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js`.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this issue, put these two lines in your *index.html* page.

```
<script>var exports = {"__esModule": true};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/main.js">
```

Make sure to check your *main.js* file path.

Comment: This only works if you don't have any `require()` statements in your code.

Answer (score 2):

I hit this error shortly after switching to "Node 16 + ESM + strict" tsconfig.json.

I think the ESM change was the bit that caused it.

I had to bisect the file to figure out the root cause:

```
exports.webhookTaskProcessor = functions.firestore
  .document("items/{itemId}/tasks/{taskId}")
  .onCreate((_change, context) => {
    processItemTasks(context.params.itemId);
  });
```

This fixed it:

```
export const webhookTaskProcessor = functions.firestore
  .document("items/{itemId}/tasks/{taskId}")
  .onCreate((_change, context) => {
    processItemTasks(context.params.itemId);
  });
```

Would be rad if the error message was a little more helpful. I hope this breadcrumb is useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are are using webpack along with babel-loader and @babel/preset-env, then make sure to callout loose and modules. So instead of the following:

```json
"presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
```

instead do

```json
"presets": [["@babel/preset-env", { "loose": true, "modules": false }]],
```

Comment: Man you are amazing

Answer (score 1):

For some ASP.NET projects `import` and `export` may not be used at all in your Typescripts.

The question's error showed up when I attempted to do so and I only discovered later that I just needed to add the generated JS script to the *View* like so:

```
<script src="~/scripts/js/[GENERATED_FILE].Index.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may be the mismatched configuration.

1. Working solution 1 below give you a correct configuration for ES Module.
2. Working solution 2 below give you a correct configuration for CommonJS.
3. Mixed solution 1+2 give you an Error.

I just post partial content here, for clarity.
Github project https://github.com/jmmvkr/ts-express/
have a complete set of files demonstrate the working solution 1 and solution 2.

Working solution 1, ES Module

```
/* Configuration for ES Module */

// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "es6", // or "esnext"
    }
}
// package.json
{
    "type": "module", // type is module
}
```

Working solution 2, CommonJS

```
/* Configuration for CommonJS */

// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
    }
}
// package.json
{
    "type": "", // type is NOT module
}
```

Mixed, do NOT work

```
/* Mixed, got ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope */

// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
    }
}
// package.json
{
    "type": "module", // type is module
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not answering the question directly, but no stackoverflow thread mentionned this  case, took me a while to debug, and so adding it here in case it could help someone in the future.

I had the error "exports is not defined" coming from an imported NPM module. Changing my typescript config did nothing as I had no control over the imported third-party code. The problem was an invalid import syntax for that package. For example, I had imported "@mui/material/TextField/TextField", yet the correct import was supposed to be "@mui/material/TextField".

Answer (score 1):

So this is a super generic TypeScript error and this StackOverflow question is the first result for various queries I made researching my problem. It has 385k views.

For those with Angular / TypeScript and an Angular Library using ng-packagr seeing a generic "***ReferenceError: exports is not defined***", you'll need to define `public-api.ts` for each feature/component/service such that you include it with `index.ts` such as found in this [repo](https://github.com/tomastrajan/angular-library-architecture-example/tree/master/projects/some-lib/src/lib/feature-c) for this [article](https://tomastrajan.medium.com/the-best-way-to-architect-your-angular-libraries-87959301d3d3)

- Node 16 or 18 (18 is LTS next week)
- Angular 2+ (14 currently)
- TypeScript 4.6.4-4.8.2

Several shallow examples go something like this referencing [Creating Libraries](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries)

```bash
ng new workspace --no-create-application
cd workspace
ng generate app home --routing=true --style=scss
ng generate app admin --routing=true --style=scss
ng generate library lib
... # include your library 'lib' into your application 'home'
ng build lib --watch &
ng serve home --open
```

What's not directly explained is your `index.ts` and `public-api.ts` files need to be in each feature/component/service. Such as these example features A, B, and C in the repo below if you have a complex library. [repo](https://github.com/tomastrajan/angular-library-architecture-example/tree/master/projects/some-lib/src/lib) has the following:

- src/lib

  - feature-a

    - [index.ts](https://github.com/tomastrajan/angular-library-architecture-example/blob/master/projects/some-lib/src/lib/feature-a/index.ts) (referencing only `./public-api`)
    - [public-api.ts](https://github.com/tomastrajan/angular-library-architecture-example/blob/master/projects/some-lib/src/lib/feature-a/public-api.ts) (referencing only exported files in the directory)
  - feature-b

    - [index.ts](https://github.com/tomastrajan/angular-library-architecture-example/blob/master/projects/some-lib/src/lib/feature-b/index.ts) (referencing only `./public-api`)
    - [public-api.ts](https://github.com/tomastrajan/angular-library-architecture-example/blob/master/projects/some-lib/src/lib/feature-b/public-api.ts) (referencing only exported files in the directory)
  - feature-c

    - [index.ts](https://github.com/tomastrajan/angular-library-architecture-example/blob/master/projects/some-lib/src/lib/feature-c/index.ts) (referencing only `./public-api`)
    - [public-api.ts](https://github.com/tomastrajan/angular-library-architecture-example/blob/master/projects/some-lib/src/lib/feature-c/public-api.ts) (referencing only exported files in the directory)

Answer (score 1):

Hello o fix this probleme by using this :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",  // ️ set this to es6
    // "module": "commonjs", // ️ REMOVE this (if browser env)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try what @iFreilicht suggested above. If that didn't work after you've installed webpack and all, you may have just copied a webpack configuration from somewhere online and configured there that you want the output to support CommonJS by mistake. Make sure this isn't the case in `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || "development",
  entry: { 
    index: "./src/js/index.ts"
  },
  ...
  ...
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',         <==== DELETE THIS LINE
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: "[name].bundle.js"
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and fixed it by changing the JS packages loading order.

Check the order in which the packages you need are being called and load them in an appropriate order.

In my specific case (not using module bundler) I needed to load `Redux`, then `Redux Thunk`, then `React Redux`. Loading `React Redux` before `Redux Thunk` would give me `exports is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but my setup required a different solution.

I'm using the `create-react-app-rewired` package with a `config-overrides.js` file. Previously, I was using the `addBabelPresets` import (in the `override()` method) from `customize-cra` and decided to abstract those presets to a separate file. Coincidentally, this solved my problem.

I added `useBabelRc()` to the `override()` method in `config-overrides.js` and created a `babel.config.js` file with the following:

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        '@babel/preset-react',
        '@babel/preset-env'
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I stuck with such error in a `SSR` client part because it used a lib which was built with `tsconfig.json` `compilerOptions` as `target: ES5` what brought using `CommonJS` for module resolution [tsc CLI Options Compiler Options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html#compiler-options): `target === "ES3" or "ES5" ? "CommonJS" : "ES6"`. While it used the target `ESNext`.

Answer (score 0):

As `ES5`/`ES2009` doesn't support modules (import/export/require) on the **client** / **browser** you have to use libraries, which bundle the modules into a single file, which can be included via `<script>` tag, such as

- [Browserify](https://github.com/browserify/browserify)
- [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/)

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19059825/5164462).

Answer (score -2):

```
  {
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "./",
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "declaration": false,
      "module": "esnext",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "target": "es5",
      "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
      "lib": ["es2018", "dom"]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some context to your answer or some explanation so the user can understand what was done. Only posting a JSON may not be as helpful...

Answer (score -2):

If you are just using interfaces for types, leave out the `export` keyword and ts can pick up on the types without needing to import. They key is you cannot use `import`/`export` anywhere.

```
export interface Person {
   name: string;
   age: number;
}
```

into

```
interface Person {
   name: string;
   age: number;
}
```