# Typescript - Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: typescript

Im getting this error message (*Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined*) when trying to import other ts files in the main app.ts

**app.ts**

```
import { LanguagesConfigs } from './LanguagesConfigs';
let languagesConfigs = new LanguagesConfigs();
```

**LanguagesConfigs.ts**

```
export class LanguagesConfigs {
 code
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true
    }
}
```

I compile it in visual studio code. It generates the .js and .js.map files

Note: I'm not using frames like angular, just plain typescript.
Note2: CommonJS is installed in the project ([Typescript ReferenceError: exports is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042889/typescript-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined))

Comment: can you mention the typescript version you are using ? `tsc -v`

Comment: typescript 2.4.2
npm 3.10.10

Comment: seems to work on my end. Can you share more info ?

Comment: LanguageConfigs filename though is different from the imports which has LanguageSConfigs I assume you have the correct name locally

Comment: Yes, I have the correct name locally. I'll edit it

Comment: can you share a repo which reconstructs the issue?

Comment: @qballer
https://github.com/gastikirs/buggedtypescript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use `export` in your code while in your `tsconfig.json` you have `"module": "commonjs"` the result code assume `commonjs` module style.

For example:

```
export class Foo{}
```

Will result is:

```
.
.
.
exports.Foo = Foo;
```

So when you try to run the result `js` code you will get this error if the environment doesn't support `commonjs`.

For example, browsers do not support `commonjs` but `nodejs` does.
You can add `commonjs` support to the browser by using [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) or just add [browserify](http://browserify.org/)

Comment: Installed browserify globally with npm but I still get the error!

Comment: what do you mean "installed globally"? you must also include the script in your html...

Comment: I mean, installed browserify, tried making a bundle.js, included it on the html with script tag, but nothing.

Comment: running `browserify -e app.js -o bundle.js` should create one js file that works on the browser.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But is it necessary to use browserify? Doesn't typescript natively support import statements?

Comment: typescript does not polyfill any module syntax, like require or commonjs. it will only output javascript that uses the requested module syntax. (According to the "module" in your tsconfig.json)

Comment: Thanks @gilamran for the browserify tip. Problem solved!