# Transpiling Typescript to ES5 with Visual Studio 2017 - Exports is Not Defined

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am attempting to use Visual Studio 2017 to integrate Typescript into an existing ASP.NET MVC project. While I understand one may normally use task runners and/or bundlers such as Webpack to transpile "newer" JS into ES5, according to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/javascript-in-vs-2017), it appears as if Visual Studio 2017 should handle the transpiling for you.

However, I am receiving the following error when I run the web site in the browser:

```
ReferenceError: exports is not defined[Learn More]
```

My current .tsconfig is as follows:

```
  {
  "compileOnSave": true,

  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./Scripts/out/",
    "rootDir": "./Scripts/src"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot",
    "outDir",
    "./Scripts/out/"
  ],
  "lib": [
    "es2016",
    "dom",
    "es5"
  ]

}
```

I have tried removing the `"module": "commonjs"` line, and adding the es5 lib as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042889/typescript-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined), but received the same error.

App-slider is a module I wrote; hyperform was installed through npm. Both are default exports.

```
 import hyperform from "hyperform";
import AppSlider from "./app-slider";
let appSlider = new AppSlider(null);
let $hyperForm = hyperform("window");
let form: HTMLFormElement  = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
let prevButton: HTMLButtonElement = <HTMLButtonElement>document.getElementById("prev");
let nextButton: HTMLButtonElement = <HTMLButtonElement>document.getElementById("next");

prevButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        appSlider.showPrev();
});

nextButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (form.checkValidity()) {
        appSlider.showNext();
    }
});
```

The generated main.js

```
   "use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var hyperform_1 = require("hyperform");
var app_slider_1 = require("./app-slider");
var appSlider = new app_slider_1.default(null);
var $hyperForm = hyperform_1.default("window");
var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
var prevButton = document.getElementById("prev");
var nextButton = document.getElementById("next");
prevButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    appSlider.showPrev();
});
nextButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (form.checkValidity()) {
        appSlider.showNext();
    }
});
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

If I change the "module" option to es6, I get a different error:

```
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

I am using TypeScript 2.5. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I've got this problem as well.  According to the qn you link to and my understanding, once the transpilling is successfully done then the `tsconfig.json` is no longer relevant.  Because you, and I have a runtime error.  It seems to me that the problem is that `CommonJS` is not being included at runtime.

Comment: did you find a solution

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `.tsconfig` file is not getting parsed - can you please rename it to `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. The file was named correctly (tsconfig.json); I just put the wrong name in my question. Thanks.