# Typescript - 'exports' is undefined in scripts.bundle.js file

Tags: angular, typescript

When I run my project I get this error:

`SCRIPT5009: 'exports' is undefined`
in the file: **scripts.bundle.js** 
at this line:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

It appears that "exports" and "require" is not defined.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Looks like duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042889/typescript-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined

Comment: @PranayKumar, it didn't work for me

Comment: What version of Typescript are you using?

Comment: @ Und3rTow , tsc -v
Version 2.6.2