# Changing module from commonjs to anything else breaks angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my `tsconfig.json` file, I have:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "baseUrl": "./node_modules/"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings"
  ]
}
```

Transpiling to JavaScript works fine, but throws an error in the browser. (exports is not defined). If I remove commonJS as noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042889/typescript-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined), then it can no longer resolve the import statment:

```
 import { angular } from "angular";
```

...and it won't transpile. What am I missing here?

**Updated:**

As requested in the comments, a file tree for project structure. The tree actually has 250+ directories and several thousand files, it has been abbreviated to only show the relevant bits:

```
.
├── bugzy-work-timer
│   ├── app.php
│   ├── css
│   │   └── 01-timer.css
│   ├── js
│   │   └── footer
│   │       ├── timer.js
│   │       └── timer.ts
│   ├── manifest.sig
│   ├── manifest.xml
│   └── tests
├── move-unused-apps.sh
├── node_modules
│   └── angular
│       ├── angular-csp.css
│       ├── angular.js
│       ├── angular.min.js
│       ├── angular.min.js.gzip
│       ├── angular.min.js.map
│       ├── bower.json
│       ├── index.js
│       ├── LICENSE.md
│       ├── package.json
│       └── README.md
├── package-lock.json
├── phpunit.xml
├── tsconfig.json
├── tsd.json
├── tslint.json
├── typings
│   ├── index.d.ts
│   ├── modules
│   │   └── angular
│   │       ├── index.d.ts
│   │       └── typings.json
│   └── tsd.d.ts
└── update-all.sh
```

Comment: can you show your project structure? and below is tsconfig template generate from Angular CLI. Maybe types definitions are missing. {
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}

Comment: @wannadream - updated per your request.