# Why does typescript assume that there is always a global exports object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

When you use Commonjs as the module in tsconfig, and export a class typescript will add 'Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });' to the output code.

Other stack overflow questions have touched on this ([Typescript ReferenceError: exports is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042889/typescript-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined)) but I don't understand *why* typescript is making that assumption.

Comment: Its because of the concept of es6  modules. Everything is encapsulated.This is not constrained only to typescript. Its generally to es6 modules/ commonjs .

Comment: In brief, CommonJS defines a global `exports`, so TypeScript expects there to be one.