# Exports is not defined ia tsc'ed (js) files

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm relatively new to typescript and I quite do not understand why after performing `tsc Program.ts` and then running

`Program.js` in browser it yells at me `ReferenceError: exports is not defined`

Program.ts

```
import { TestClass } from './TestClass';

var tc = new TestClass();

console.log(tc.Test("test"));
```

TestClass.ts

```
import {Data} from "./Data";

export class TestClass
{
    constructor() {}

    Test(originalString:string)
    {
        console.log(Data.Symbols["John"] + " " + originalString);
    }
}
```

Data.ts

```
export abstract class Data
{
    public static Symbols:{[symbol: string] : string} = 
    {
        "John":"a5fq36831v",
    }
}
```

package-lock.json

```
{
  "requires": true,
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "dependencies":
  {
    "uniq": 
    {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/uniq/-/uniq-1.0.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-sxxa6CVIRKOoKBVBzisEuGWnNP8="
    }
  }
}
```

I have `npm i @types/node` installed

I have seen this thread: [Typescript ReferenceError: exports is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042889/typescript-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined)

but I don't have any `tsconfig.json` or `babelrc` file.

This trick works partly for me `<script>var exports = {};</script>` t

because after that `ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Is it possible to make it work without installing additional tons of software?

```
npm i common-js

npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Repo\Master\src\TypeScript\package.json'
npm WARN saveError EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Repo\Master\src\TypeScript\package-lock.json.1161578677' -> 'C:\Repo\src\TypeScript\package-lock.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Repo\Master\src\TypeScript\package.json'
npm WARN TypeScript No description
npm WARN TypeScript No repository field.
npm WARN TypeScript No README data
npm WARN TypeScript No license field.

+ common-js@0.3.8
added 1 package in 2.141s
PS C:\Repo\Master\src\TypeScript> tsc ProgramParser.ts

ReferenceError: exports is not defined Program.js:2:1
ReferenceError: Parser is not defined html.html:40:6
```

Comment: have you checked this link to solve the `ReferenceError: require is not defined` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined

Comment: No `tsconfig.json`? That sounds alarming. `tsconfig.json` is the configuration file on how the transpiling should be done. I guess you can use flags if you want to avoid making `tsconfig.json`. But more importantly, are you building a node.js app or a web app? You mentioned browser so I assume web app, then I think what you need is something like `tsc --module es6 `. `exports` is not defined error shows because your `tsc` command probably transpiled for commonjs which is for nodejs apps, not web app.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042889/typescript-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether commonjs is installed in environment or not .

Comment: Try adding     "module": "es6" in package.json

Comment: The thing is that I don't have package json :P I have something like ``package-lock.json``

Comment: I guess best solution will be importing requires.js in this file

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a `tsconfig.json` file at the root of your project that specifies the compilation target. Something like this will most likely work:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015",
      "es5",
      "es6"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can offer two options:

- You can use a bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.github.io) or [Parcel](https://parceljs.org) to take your TypeScript code and make it run in the browser, with the bundle being responsible for handling your file imports.
- You can use use the [tsconfig](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) compiler option `outFile` to make TypeScript only create a single file for all of your front end JavaScript