# Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined //year 2020

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsc

I'm stuck. I tried many solutions but none of them works.
Trying to implement a module, I get this error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

I tried [solution from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042889/typescript-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined), but it does not work. Changing anything in tsconfing does not make any difference. I added `var exports = {};` into scripts in HTML file and error changes from "exports" to "require" - dead end.

server node:

```
var fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var { request } = require('http');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.listen(3533);
```

html:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="testing site">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>simple testin </title>
</head>
<body >
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="webscripts/run_scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="webscripts/library.js"></script>  
</html>
```

library.ts:

```
export function appearSomeTestingSentence()  {
    document.write('111111');
};
```

library.js:

```
  "use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
exports.appearSomeTestingSentence = void 0;
exports.appearSomeTestingSentence = function () {
    document.write('111111');
};
```

run_scripts.ts:

```
import {appearSomeTestingSentence} from './library.js';
appearSomeTestingSentence();
```

run_scripts.js:

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var library_1 = require("./library");
library_1.appearSomeTestingSentence();
```

Comment: There are 17 answers on the linked question you claim doesn't work. Which answer did you try? How did you implement the solution? How did they not work?

Comment: I tryied to comment ' "module": "commonjs" '
I put: ' <script>var exports = {};</script> ' into my html file.
it changed error code in to "require" instead "imports".
i tryied to change tsconfig like: ' {
  "compilerOptions": {     
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",    
  }
}'
 nothing works!

Comment: `<script type=module>` is not for CommonJS.

Comment: i have changed it Aluan Haddad, no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i sort it out. I had to delete *.js files before i compile with tsc and i had to restart tsc after changing something in tsconfig. Problem solved after
changing module to`"module" : "ESNext"` in tsconfig file.