# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined react-rails

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, sprockets, react-rails

I'm trying to integrate react-rails 2.6.1 within my rails 4.2.11 app.

initially started with webpacker but it's giving me troubles with the actual prod deployment, so I removed webpacker and just pack stuff with sprockets 3.7.2.

The page is loaded properly but the `react_component` is not shown.

in the html source it's just rendered as a div:

```
<div data-react-class="Sidebar" data-react-props="..." data-react-cache-id="Sidebar-0"></div>
```

but nothing is shown.

in the console I can see:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

which causes later on:

`Cannot find component: 'Sidebar'. Make sure your component is available to render.`

this is the definition of my react component:

```
import React from "react"

class Sidebar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<p> hello from react </p> );
  }
}
```

I've tried moving imports from application.js up and down, (according to https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/wiki/Troubleshooting) to no help.

Comment: Did you export default Sidebar ?

Comment: I removed the export as it was actually raising `exports is not defined` and I read that sprockets actually places everything in one file, so no export is required.

Answer (score 1):

Try to export your component to be able to import it

```js
import React from "react"

class Sidebar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<p> hello from react </p> );
  }
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Comment: Thanks, with the export included I get in the console: `Sidebar.self.js?body=1:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at Sidebar.self.js?body=1:1:23` line 1 on Sidebar.self.js contains: 

`Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});`

Comment: it's like exports and require are in some other library, (react_ujs?) but they don't work.

Comment: {
  "presets": [ ["env", {"modules": false} ]]
} 
add this in your .babelrc.js

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042889/typescript-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined 

one of this solutions should fix your issue

Comment: my .babelrc contains `{
  "presets": [
    "airbnb"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "add-module-exports",
    ["transform-replace-object-assign", { "moduleSpecifier": "object.assign" }],
  ],
}
`

changing it to:  `{
  "presets": [
    "airbnb",
    ["env", {"modules": false} ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "add-module-exports",
    ["transform-replace-object-assign", { "moduleSpecifier": "object.assign" }],
  ],
}` didn't help

Comment: these changes are mostly for TS, I don't have that, it's sprockets and js, removing commonjs I'm not sure how to do that, as I don't see it anywhere. I tried adding the ` <script>var exports = {};</script>` workaround in both flavours (from that post) but no improvements