# How do I let the browser allow me to use imports? (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, import

### Context

I have these two TypeScript files:

```ts
// something.ts

let x = 3;

export default x;
```

```ts
// index.ts

import x from "./something";

console.log(x);
```

under these `tsconfig.json` settings:

```json
{
  ...
    "target": "es2016",
  ...
    // "module": "commonjs" /* <- commented out */
}
```

when I compile this into JavaScript, I get these two files (which is what I expect):

```js
// something.js

let x = 3;
export default x;
```

```js
// index.js

import x from "./something";
console.log(x);
```

Now, I've linked the `index.js` file from my HTML file like so:

```html
<script src="./dist/index.js"></script>
```

### Problem

When I try opening this up using Live Server, I get this error in the console:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

**So, how do I fix this?**

### What I've tried

1. Adding back the `"module": "commonjs"` line in my `tsconfig.json` file

This results in a different error message appearing in the console:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined`

As per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042889/typescript-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined), a suggested solution is to comment out the `"module": "commonjs"` line, which essentially throws my situation into an infinite loop...

2. Adding `"type": "module"` to the `<script>` tag and `package.json`

From [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import), a suggested solution is to add `"type": "module"` to the `<script>` tag:

```html
<script type="module" src="./dist/index.js"></script>
```

but now I get this error message:

`GET http://127.0.0.1:5501/dist/something net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`.

In the same post, another suggestion was to add "type": "module" to the `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.6.2"
  }
}
```

and from what I've observed, this doesn't really do anything.

Comment: When you do use `"module": "commonjs"` how do the compiled files look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are really really really close. In ESM (in browser) imports, you must provide the file name extension, so you need to do:

```js
import something from "./something.js";
```

instead of simply

```js
import something from "./something";
```

Your other code didn't work because the browser runs on, well... the browser. That means we're not in a NodeJS environment so modules don't work so magically. So, the caveats of ESM imports:

- You can't import npm packages
- All imports must be an absolute URL or start with `./` or `/`
- The browser doesn't automatically add a file extension; you'll have to specify yourself (e.g. `import something from "./something.js";` instead of `import something from "./something";`)
- You must specify `type="module"` in your HTML script tag to tell the browser that it's a module you're looking at
- Please don't use this in production, because...

  - If you have nested imports, the browser can't load them concurrently; they have to be loaded one by one
  - It's not as fast (duh)
  - The feature is quite new so isn't really enhanced that much

**The real solution:**
Use a bundler instead!!

Why?
A bundler (the most popular is perhaps [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org)) finds all the imports and exports in your code and combines it all into one file.
**Why you should use a bundler:**

- Everyone is using it
- It's the standard
- It's popular
- ...
- It enhances page performance
- You get other goodies like minification and whatnot
- You can import (some) npm packages

That doesn't mean we should *never* use in-browser imports. It's totally fine when you're using it in development, as it's easier to set up anyways. Vite, a popular development framework, takes advantage of this to improve the DX (developer experience) by removing the bundler wait time every time you re-run your code.

But again, don't use this in production.

*I suggest you use a bundler since you have Node and TS set up anyways. It'll be easier in the long run...*

Comment: "_All imports must end with .js_": This is not correct: browsers don't discriminate resources by file extension. Rather, each imported script must be served with the correct media type and parse as a valid ES module.

Comment: @jsejcksn true true. I added that for the sake of simplicity but updated the answer just now for the sake of your comment.

Comment: "_the browser can't load them concurrently_": This is also not true. See these posts: [ESM and HTTP/2](https://betterprogramming.pub/2020-004-the-rollout-of-modules-is-complete-d25f04870284), [V8: Modules](https://v8.dev/features/modules#defer). (ESM dependencies are loaded concurrently).