# import/export typscript files, cant find my js file when running http-server, ERR_ABORTED 404

Tags: typescript

I can´t seem to fix this problem, i have moved around my files tried different path and stuff but still getting this error. I understand that this error means that I cant find the config.js file but why?

Current error:

> GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/dist/config net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

using http-server to view in my chrome browser. I have tried live-server as well.

**File structure:**

- dist

  - index.js
  - config.js
- src

  - index.ts
  - config.ts
- index.html

**index.ts**, here I have tried to change path to all kind of stuff

```ts
import config from "./config";
const API_KEY = config.API_KEY;

console.log(API_KEY);
```

**index.html** , here I tried defer as well,

```html
<body>
    <script type="module" src="./dist/index.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./dist/config.js"></script>
</body>
```

**config.ts**

```ts
const config ={
    API_KEY:"api_key",
};

export default config;
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
"compilerOptions": {
  "target": "ES6",
  "module": "ES6",
  "outDir": "./dist",
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
  "strict": true,  
  "skipLibCheck": true
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I let the browser allow me to use imports? (TypeScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71454189/how-do-i-let-the-browser-allow-me-to-use-imports-typescript)

Comment: Oops, I meant this one (the dupe target) [How to resolve Node.js ES6 (ESM) Modules with the TypeScript Compiler (TSC). TSC doesn't emit the correct file-ext](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44979976/283366)

Comment: My hope was not to use webpack, but I went that way at the end seems easier when I read about it, thanks for the link!