# How can i correctly config my typescript nodejs project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, commonjs

I am trying to figure this out for hours but i can not solve this seemingly easy problem.

I want to write an nodejs app with typescript.
I want to use the import statement like `import express from 'express';` because then I get autocomplete in visual studio code. With require this does not work.

How can i export a function? What standard should i use? es6, commonjs,...?

How should i configure my tsconfig.json?

//tsconfig.json

```
{
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6" /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */,
    "module": "ES6" /* Specify what module code is generated. */,
    "moduleResolution": "node" /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */,
    "outDir": "dist" /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */,
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */,
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you already have nodejs installed on your computer/server. I did these steps this morning, created a new node project with typescript. You can of course choose other versions as you like.

1. Run command **npm init -y**
2. Run command **npm install --save-dev typescript**
3. Create **tsconfig.json**
4. add code to **tsconfig.json**

   {
   "compilerOptions": {
   "module": "commonjs",
   "esModuleInterop": true,
   "target": "es6",
   "moduleResolution": "node",
   "sourceMap": true,
   "outDir": "dist"
   },
   "lib": ["es2015"]
   }
5. Run command **npm install --save express@4.17.1**
6. Run command **npm install -save-dev @types/express@4.17.1**
7. Create **app.ts** in src folder
8. Add code to **app.ts**

   import express from 'express';
   const app = express();
   const port = 3000;

   app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.send('Hello World!');
   });

   app.listen(port, () => {
   return console.log(`Express is listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
   });
9. Update **package.json** with **"main": "dist/app.js"**
10. Run command to compile ts code **npx tsc**
11. Run command **node dist/app.js** to execute program

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This throws than an error `ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope`.
I use in my typescript files no `require` anymore. Just es6 export and import. So i have to set the compiler option to : `"module": "es6",` , or am I wrong?

After that I get the error: `Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\ticketing\dist\routes\admin' imported from C:\ticketing\dist\app.js`

The compiled app.js has this line: `import adminRouter from './routes/admin';`

Comment: According to this answer, yes [https://stackoverflow.com/a/43999062/1349916](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43999062/1349916). Try to create a new project, follow my steps and then compare with your old project.

Comment: I fixed it. I changed `import { createOrder } from '../paypal/paypal';` to `import { createOrder } from '../paypal/paypal.js';`