# ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope after compiling app

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm developing a simple node cli using commander.

src/bin/cli.ts (simplified code example)

app uses ESM imports and barrels

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// libs
import { Command } from 'commander'
import chalk from 'chalk'
import figlet from 'figlet'

// initializers
import {
  astro,
} from 'lib'

// helpers
import { Options } from 'helpers'

const program = new Command()

// eslint-disable-next-line no-console
console.info(chalk.green(figlet.textSync('scaffold-cli', { horizontalLayout: 'full' })))

program
  .version('0.0.1')
  .description('A CLI that scaffolds common tools and configs')
  .usage('[options] <file>')
  .option('-a, --astro', Options.astro, astro)
  .parse(process.argv)
```

Can't run or compile the app:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
                      ^

ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/Users/user/Documents/dev/projects/scaffold-cli/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
```

If I remove type: module from package.json I get this error message instead:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /Users/user/Documents/dev/projects/scaffold-cli/node_modules/chalk/source/index.js from /Users/user/Documents/dev/projects/scaffold-cli/dist/bin/cli.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /Users/user/Documents/dev/projects/scaffold-cli/dist/bin/cli.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/dev/projects/scaffold-cli/dist/bin/cli.js:8:33) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

I'm using the recommended base ts config for [Node 16](https://github.com/tsconfig/bases/blob/main/bases/node16.json) :

```
{
  "display": "Node 16",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2021"],
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "target": "es2021",

    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",

    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "removeComments": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "error",
    "noImplicitAny": true,

    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": { "@configs/*": ["../configs"], "@lib/*": ["lib"] }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "types.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "configs"],
  "ts-node": {
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"],
    "esm": true,
    "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

package.json (simplified):

```
"main": "dist/bin/cli.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bin": {
    "scaffold-cli": "dist/bin/cli.js"
  },
"type": "module",
```

How do I solve this? It feels like using the recommended config for Node, should compile without any errors. I'm not using any bundler like webpack. I just build with tsc.

Comment: What kind of app are you developing: api, web ssr, spa csr, daemon? Share us the entrypoint js file, package.json

Comment: I've updated my post to include the requested info

Comment: You _probably_ want your javascript output to not be compiled to commonjs, but to keep ESM. If so, your `module` should be set to `node16` and not `commonjs`

Comment: That change does not help unfortunately. I don't mind if it's compiled to commonjs, but the compilation has to work.

Comment: I'm wondering if I need to add Babel? To take advantage of ES6 import / export? Or it should work without it?

Answer (score -2):

Is that answer would be able to help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43999062/16780054 ? It seems that you should remove

```
"module": "commonjs",
```

from your ts.config if commonJS is not installed.

Comment: commonJS is nothing you install, it's a node module format.