# Error through importing animejs into typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, ecmascript-6, anime.js

I was trying to import anime.js into a typescript project after installing it via npm. Before that, I installed and initialized typescript, executed commands:

```
npm install typescript
npx tsc -init
```

So, now i am have a completely clear project with default tsconfig.json file:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig to read more about this file */

    /* Projects */
    // "incremental": true,                              /* Save .tsbuildinfo files to allow for incremental compilation of projects. */
    // "composite": true,                                /* Enable constraints that allow a TypeScript project to be used with project references. */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./.tsbuildinfo",              /* Specify the path to .tsbuildinfo incremental compilation file. */
    // "disableSourceOfProjectReferenceRedirect": true,  /* Disable preferring source files instead of declaration files when referencing composite projects. */
    // "disableSolutionSearching": true,                 /* Opt a project out of multi-project reference checking when editing. */
    // "disableReferencedProjectLoad": true,             /* Reduce the number of projects loaded automatically by TypeScript. */

    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es2016",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    // "lib": [],                                        /* Specify a set of bundled library declaration files that describe the target runtime environment. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                                /* Specify what JSX code is generated. */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,                   /* Enable experimental support for TC39 stage 2 draft decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,                    /* Emit design-type metadata for decorated declarations in source files. */
    // "jsxFactory": "",                                 /* Specify the JSX factory function used when targeting React JSX emit, e.g. 'React.createElement' or 'h'. */
    // "jsxFragmentFactory": "",                         /* Specify the JSX Fragment reference used for fragments when targeting React JSX emit e.g. 'React.Fragment' or 'Fragment'. */
    // "jsxImportSource": "",                            /* Specify module specifier used to import the JSX factory functions when using 'jsx: react-jsx*'. */
    // "reactNamespace": "",                             /* Specify the object invoked for 'createElement'. This only applies when targeting 'react' JSX emit. */
    // "noLib": true,                                    /* Disable including any library files, including the default lib.d.ts. */
    // "useDefineForClassFields": true,                  /* Emit ECMAScript-standard-compliant class fields. */
    // "moduleDetection": "auto",                        /* Control what method is used to detect module-format JS files. */

    /* Modules */
    "module": "commonjs",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                                  /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */
    // "moduleResolution": "node",                       /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                                  /* Specify the base directory to resolve non-relative module names. */
    // "paths": {},                                      /* Specify a set of entries that re-map imports to additional lookup locations. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                                   /* Allow multiple folders to be treated as one when resolving modules. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                                  /* Specify multiple folders that act like './node_modules/@types'. */
    // "types": [],                                      /* Specify type package names to be included without being referenced in a source file. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,                     /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */
    // "moduleSuffixes": [],                             /* List of file name suffixes to search when resolving a module. */
    // "resolveJsonModule": true,                        /* Enable importing .json files. */
    // "noResolve": true,                                /* Disallow 'import's, 'require's or '<reference>'s from expanding the number of files TypeScript should add to a project. */

    /* JavaScript Support */
    // "allowJs": true,                                  /* Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the 'checkJS' option to get errors from these files. */
    // "checkJs": true,                                  /* Enable error reporting in type-checked JavaScript files. */
    // "maxNodeModuleJsDepth": 1,                        /* Specify the maximum folder depth used for checking JavaScript files from 'node_modules'. Only applicable with 'allowJs'. */

    /* Emit */
    // "declaration": true,                              /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                           /* Create sourcemaps for d.ts files. */
    // "emitDeclarationOnly": true,                      /* Only output d.ts files and not JavaScript files. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                                /* Create source map files for emitted JavaScript files. */
    // "outFile": "./",                                  /* Specify a file that bundles all outputs into one JavaScript file. If 'declaration' is true, also designates a file that bundles all .d.ts output. */
    // "outDir": "./",                                   /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
    // "removeComments": true,                           /* Disable emitting comments. */
    // "noEmit": true,                                   /* Disable emitting files from a compilation. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                            /* Allow importing helper functions from tslib once per project, instead of including them per-file. */
    // "importsNotUsedAsValues": "remove",               /* Specify emit/checking behavior for imports that are only used for types. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,                       /* Emit more compliant, but verbose and less performant JavaScript for iteration. */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                                 /* Specify the root path for debuggers to find the reference source code. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,                          /* Include sourcemap files inside the emitted JavaScript. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                            /* Include source code in the sourcemaps inside the emitted JavaScript. */
    // "emitBOM": true,                                  /* Emit a UTF-8 Byte Order Mark (BOM) in the beginning of output files. */
    // "newLine": "crlf",                                /* Set the newline character for emitting files. */
    // "stripInternal": true,                            /* Disable emitting declarations that have '@internal' in their JSDoc comments. */
    // "noEmitHelpers": true,                            /* Disable generating custom helper functions like '__extends' in compiled output. */
    // "noEmitOnError": true,                            /* Disable emitting files if any type checking errors are reported. */
    // "preserveConstEnums": true,                       /* Disable erasing 'const enum' declarations in generated code. */
    // "declarationDir": "./",                           /* Specify the output directory for generated declaration files. */
    // "preserveValueImports": true,                     /* Preserve unused imported values in the JavaScript output that would otherwise be removed. */

    /* Interop Constraints */
    // "isolatedModules": true,                          /* Ensure that each file can be safely transpiled without relying on other imports. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,             /* Allow 'import x from y' when a module doesn't have a default export. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,                         /* Disable resolving symlinks to their realpath. This correlates to the same flag in node. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                            /* Enable error reporting for expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,                         /* When type checking, take into account 'null' and 'undefined'. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,                      /* When assigning functions, check to ensure parameters and the return values are subtype-compatible. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,                      /* Check that the arguments for 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods match the original function. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,             /* Check for class properties that are declared but not set in the constructor. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when 'this' is given the type 'any'. */
    // "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,               /* Default catch clause variables as 'unknown' instead of 'any'. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                             /* Ensure 'use strict' is always emitted. */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when local variables aren't read. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,                       /* Raise an error when a function parameter isn't read. */
    // "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,               /* Interpret optional property types as written, rather than adding 'undefined'. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,                        /* Enable error reporting for codepaths that do not explicitly return in a function. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,               /* Enable error reporting for fallthrough cases in switch statements. */
    // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,                 /* Add 'undefined' to a type when accessed using an index. */
    // "noImplicitOverride": true,                       /* Ensure overriding members in derived classes are marked with an override modifier. */
    // "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,       /* Enforces using indexed accessors for keys declared using an indexed type. */
    // "allowUnusedLabels": true,                        /* Disable error reporting for unused labels. */
    // "allowUnreachableCode": true,                     /* Disable error reporting for unreachable code. */

    /* Completeness */
    // "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,                      /* Skip type checking .d.ts files that are included with TypeScript. */
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }
}
```

And two files - index.html and styles.css:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="demo"></div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

styles.css:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: darkslategrey;
    height: 100vh;
}

#demo {
    display: flex;
    width: 7rem;
    height: 7rem;
    background-color: rgb(42, 136, 165);
    border-radius: 2rem;
}
```

And the tree of my project looks like this:
[Project tree image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmkpB.png)

Then i need to install anime.js, so I was going thought guide on official anime.js site:

```
npm install animejs --save
```

And install @types for it:

```
npm install --save @types/animejs
```

And when it is done, i made a new main.ts script in the root folder of the project, took the basic example of anime from their site, and compiled my project it into js with `npx tsc --watch`:

main.ts

```js
import anime from 'animejs/lib/anime.es.js';

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    anime({
        targets: '#demo',
        translateX: 250
    });
});
```

Goes into main.js:

```js
"use strict";
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const anime_es_js_1 = __importDefault(require("animejs/lib/anime.es.js"));
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    (0, anime_es_js_1.default)({
        targets: '#demo',
        translateX: 250
    });
});
```

I run the Live Server by Ritwick Dey, go to the browser and it doesn't work. No errors are shown in VS Code either.

I expected the code to be working, but instead got an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:5500/main.js:5
```

Then, i found another question, where a person asks for this error, and i tried to remove the line  `"module": "commonjs"`, as recommends in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43999062/17798036).

But after that i receive another error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

Then i tried to add `type="module"` in my index.html file, in the line, where i am importing the main.js file. So, now, it looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script type="module" src="./main.js"></script> <!-- modified -->
</head>
<body>

    <div id="demo"></div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

But it also gives an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: The specifier “animejs/lib/anime.es.js” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything. 
Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.
```

I thought, that i needed to import it via `importmap`:

```html
<script type="importmap">
        { "imports": {
            "animejs": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.js",
        } }
</script>
```

And i changed the import line to:

```js
// import anime from 'animejs/lib/anime.es.js';
import anime from "animejs";
```

But is doesn't work.The Error is still the same:

```
Uncaught TypeError: The specifier “animejs” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything. 
Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.
```

I tried to import it as a file:

```js
// import anime from ".\\node_modules\\animejs\\lib\\anime.es.js";
// import anime from ".\\node_modules\\animejs\\lib\\anime.js";
// import anime from ".\\node_modules\\animejs\\lib\\anime.min.js";
```

But every of those lines gives me a compilation error:

```
main.ts:4:19 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '.\node_modules\animejs\lib\anime.es.js'. 'C:/Users/someuser/Desktop/web/node_modules/animejs/lib/anime.es.js' implicitly ules/animejs/lib/anime.es.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

4 import anime from ".\\node_modules\\animejs\\lib\\anime.es.js";
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

There is also no compilation errors, if i do not import anything the browser shows me following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: anime is not defined
    <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:5500/main.js:8
    EventListener.handleEvent* http://127.0.0.1:5500/main.js:7
```

I also tried to change `"target": "es2016",` on `"target": "ES6",`. And add the `import anime from "animejs";` line in main.ts but it gave me the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: The specifier “animejs” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.
```

What i am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
Thanks to [@LucasA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16096881/lucas-a): the solution was to use [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/).

Comment: What I understood is that you're trying to create a web page but instead of using javascript you are using typescript for the logic part and in this scenario I'd encoraje you to use a bundler like [webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack). Webpack will manage all dependencies and compilation process for you and you just need to configure it.