# How to implement Chart.js with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js

I want to use Chartjs(chartjs.org) as my charting tool, along with TypeScript. I have installed Chartjs.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/chart.js
```

I copied the code from the Chartjs website and put it into my typescript file "analyzechart.ts"

```
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
const ctx = document.getElementById('weekly_report') as HTMLCanvasElement;

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
          beginAtZero: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

then I compile the TypeScript code into JavaScript 'tsc'.

```
"use strict";
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const auto_1 = __importDefault(require("chart.js/auto"));
const ctx = document.getElementById('weekly_report');
new auto_1.default(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

but showing an error in the browser.
"Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
  at analyzechart.js:5:23"

I need to run Chartjs in TypeScript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript ReferenceError: exports is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042889/typescript-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined)

Comment: Not addressing the specific error you mentioned, but, very important: newer versions of chart.js, if installed for instance with `npm`, *already include typescript definitions* (to check them, they are in `node_modules/chart.js/dist/types` with an index where `tsc`, if properly installed with `npm`, finds them, `node_modules/chart.js/dist/types.d`). *Don't install DefinitelyTypes types*, they are not necessary, and probably corresponding to an older version than the one you have thus messing things up.